# ParseStringConverter could not be found

Tags: c#, json.net

I'm using quick type to create a c# object from json. When I paste it into my Visual studio project I get an error on this line `[JsonConverter(typeof(ParseStringConverter))]`,

> Error CS0246  The type or namespace name 'ParseStringConverter' could
> not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
> reference?)

I haven't been able to find anything useful on this error.
Has anyone else had this issue?
I'm using VS 2022, Newtonsoft 13.0.2 and .Net 6.0 framework.

Json:

```
{
   "code":200,
   "status":"OK",
   "status_message":"Session Detail selected Successfully.",
   "data":{
      "215":{
         "agent_id":"5",
         "session_id":"215",
         "session_start_time":"02-09-2023 09:47:48",
         "session_end_time":"02-09-2023 09:57:32",
         "session_type":"AUTO",
         "TST":"00:09:44",
         "TC":"1",
         "AC":"1",
         "TCT":"00:00:12",
         "Email_time":"00:00:00",
         "Chat_time":"00:00:00",
         "SMS_time":"00:00:00",
         "TTT":"00:00:04",
         "THT":"00:00:00",
         "TDT":"00:00:12",
         "TBT":"00:00:00",
         "TIT":"00:09:20",
         "ATT":"00:00:04"
      },
      "216":{
         "agent_id":"5",
         "session_id":"216",
         "session_start_time":"02-09-2023 10:00:33",
         "session_end_time":"02-09-2023 10:01:59",
         "session_type":"AUTO",
         "TST":"00:01:26",
         "TC":"2",
         "AC":"2",
         "TCT":"00:00:43",
         "Email_time":"00:00:00",
         "Chat_time":"00:00:00",
         "SMS_time":"00:00:00",
         "TTT":"00:00:35",
         "THT":"00:00:00",
         "TDT":"00:00:05",
         "TBT":"00:00:00",
         "TIT":"00:00:38",
         "ATT":"00:00:18"
      },
      "217":{
         "agent_id":"5",
         "session_id":"217",
         "session_start_time":"02-09-2023 10:02:47",
         "session_end_time":"02-09-2023 10:06:00",
         "session_type":"AUTO",
         "TST":"00:03:13",
         "TC":"0",
         "AC":"0",
         "TCT":"00:00:00",
         "Email_time":"00:00:00",
         "Chat_time":"00:00:00",
         "SMS_time":"00:00:00",
         "TTT":"00:00:00",
         "THT":"00:00:00",
         "TDT":"00:00:00",
         "TBT":"00:01:37",
         "TIT":"00:01:36",
         "ATT":"00:00:00",
         "Break_data":[
            {
               "break_start_time":"02-09-2023 10:04:05",
               "break_end_time":"02-09-2023 10:04:19",
               "break_type":"10 Minute Break",
               "total_break_time":"00:00:14"
            },
            {
               "break_start_time":"02-09-2023 10:04:28",
               "break_end_time":"02-09-2023 10:05:06",
               "break_type":"30 Minute Lunch",
               "total_break_time":"00:00:38"
            },
            {
               "break_start_time":"02-09-2023 10:05:11",
               "break_end_time":"02-09-2023 10:05:56",
               "break_type":"Billable Adm",
               "total_break_time":"00:00:45"
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

Quicktype Object:

```
namespace QuickType
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    using System.Text.Json;
    using System.Text.Json.Serialization;
    using System.Globalization;

    public partial class SessionDetails
    {
        [JsonPropertyName("code")]
        public long Code { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("status")]
        public string Status { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("status_message")]
        public string StatusMessage { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("data")]
        public Dictionary<string, Datum> Data { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class Datum
    {
        [JsonPropertyName("agent_id")]
        [JsonConverter(typeof(ParseStringConverter))]
        public long AgentId { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("session_id")]
        [JsonConverter(typeof(ParseStringConverter))]
        public long SessionId { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("session_start_time")]
        public string SessionStartTime { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("session_end_time")]
        public string SessionEndTime { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("session_type")]
        public string SessionType { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("TST")]
        public DateTimeOffset Tst { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("TC")]
        [JsonConverter(typeof(ParseStringConverter))]
        public long Tc { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("AC")]
        [JsonConverter(typeof(ParseStringConverter))]
        public long Ac { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("TCT")]
        public DateTimeOffset Tct { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("Email_time")]
        public DateTimeOffset EmailTime { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("Chat_time")]
        public DateTimeOffset ChatTime { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("SMS_time")]
        public DateTimeOffset SmsTime { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("TTT")]
        public DateTimeOffset Ttt { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("THT")]
        public DateTimeOffset Tht { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("TDT")]
        public DateTimeOffset Tdt { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("TBT")]
        public DateTimeOffset Tbt { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("TIT")]
        public DateTimeOffset Tit { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("ATT")]
        public DateTimeOffset Att { get; set; }

        [JsonIgnore(Condition = JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingNull)]
        [JsonPropertyName("Break_data")]
        public BreakDatum[] BreakData { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class BreakDatum
    {
        [JsonPropertyName("break_start_time")]
        public string BreakStartTime { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("break_end_time")]
        public string BreakEndTime { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("break_type")]
        public string BreakType { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("total_break_time")]
        public DateTimeOffset TotalBreakTime { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I've tried re-installing newtonsoft with no effect.

Comment: You may want to clarify what is "using quick type"... As it does not look like regular VS' "paste JSON as classes"

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov it should be https://app.quicktype.io/ to my understanding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all `JsonPropertyNameAttribute` comes from `System.Text.Json` json converter (default since ASP.NET Core 3). To generate classes for Newtonsoft.Json select it in the https://app.quicktype.io/ interface:

[image]

As for `ParseStringConverter` you need to select `Complete` option in the output window:

[image]

Which will generate something like the following for `System.Text.Json`:

```
internal class ParseStringConverter : JsonConverter<long>
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type t) => t == typeof(long);

    public override long Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        var value = reader.GetString();
        long l;
        if (Int64.TryParse(value, out l))
        {
            return l;
        }
        throw new Exception("Cannot unmarshal type long");
    }

    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, long value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        JsonSerializer.Serialize(writer, value.ToString(), options);
        return;
    }

    public static readonly ParseStringConverter Singleton = new ParseStringConverter();
}
```

And for Newtonsoft:

```
internal class ParseStringConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type t) => t == typeof(long) || t == typeof(long?);

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type t, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Null) return null;
        var value = serializer.Deserialize<string>(reader);
        long l;
        if (Int64.TryParse(value, out l))
        {
            return l;
        }
        throw new Exception("Cannot unmarshal type long");
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object untypedValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (untypedValue == null)
        {
            serializer.Serialize(writer, null);
            return;
        }
        var value = (long)untypedValue;
        serializer.Serialize(writer, value.ToString());
        return;
    }

    public static readonly ParseStringConverter Singleton = new ParseStringConverter();
}
```

Also, if I remember correctly, at least in the earlier versions of Newtonsoft.Json it was not needed because it was able to automatically treat number strings as numbers. And for `System.Text.Json` this behaviour can be achieved by using `JsonNumberHandling.AllowReadingFromString` for `JsonSerializerOptions.NumberHandling`.

Comment: That was it.  I totally missed the "complete" option.  Thanks!